# Nesting Stack in Column in Flutter, widgets are disappearing due to mysterious layout logic

Tags: android, flutter, dart, layout

I want multiple `CircleAvatar`s like this

[image]

But if I don't include a `Divider` (1st child of stack, line #38), I am getting this. What is happening and why? How to fix this?

[image]

Relevant widget:

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Text('Some Text'),
        Stack(
          children: [
            const Divider(),
            const SizedBox(height: 100, width: 100),
            const Positioned(
              left: 30,
              bottom: 29,
              child: CircleAvatar(),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 120,
              bottom: 29,
              child: CircleAvatar(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[Complete code](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zk1m06abk1n0?entry=lib/main.dart)

Comment: Same thing happens when I remove the `Column` and add the `Text` in `Stack` itself. https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z8k06v48l06?entry=lib/main.dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because `stack` take its size from its parents or as much as its longest child, and when you remove the `Divider`, `SizedBox` became longest child and its width not enough for two `CircleAvatar`.

try wrap your `column` with `sizedbox` and give it `static width` or just set `double.infinity` to get screen width.

```
Column(
        children: [
          Text('Some Text'),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  left: 30,
                  bottom: 29,
                  child: CircleAvatar(),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 120,
                  bottom: 29,
                  child: CircleAvatar(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```